# How can I use formik's setSubmitting() method on onSubmit handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I try to call formik's setSubmitting method inside the onSubmit handler .
First I create a ref for formik like this :

```
const formikRef = React.createRef();
```

Then I try to call it in onSubmit handler :

```
function Add() {
    const formikRef = React.createRef();
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        setTimeout(() => {
            formikRef.setSubmitting(false);
        }, 4000);
    };

    return (
        <Formik
            innerRef={formikRef}
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >
            {(props) => {
                return (
                    <Form>
                        ...
                    </Form>
                );
            }}
        </Formik>
    );
}

export default Add;
```

But it throws an error like this :

```
TypeError: formikRef.setSubmitting is not a function
```

How can I use formik's setSubmitting() onSubmit function with or without formik's innerRef ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref`'s values in react are inside a property called `current`. the correct way would be:

```
formikRef.current.setSubmitting(false);
```